# how to make a thread in a thread subclass daemon?

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon

How to make the tread in the below class daemon so it stops once the program ends?

```
import threading
import time

class A_Class(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        print('deleted')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("running")
            time.sleep(1)

a_obj = A_Class()
a_obj.start()

time.sleep(5)
print('The time is up, the thread should end')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `daemon=True` to your `Thread.__init__()`:

```
import threading
import time

class A_Class(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon=True)

    def __del__(self):
        print('deleted')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("running")
            time.sleep(1)

a_obj = A_Class()
a_obj.start()

time.sleep(5)
print('The time is up, the thread should end')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it - set it as Daemon after calling `super().__init__()`.

```
class A_Class(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True

    def __del__(self):
        print('deleted')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("running", self.isDaemon())
            time.sleep(1)
```

---

Or use a keyword parameter:

```
class A_Class(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        print('deleted')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("running", self.isDaemon())
            time.sleep(1)

a_obj = A_Class(daemon=True)
```